# how to use corresondence theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a normal subgroup of $B$ and $B/A$ is an cyclic group with infinite order. I want to show $B$ has a normal subgroup of index $k$ for every $k$ positive using correspondence theorem, I am not sure how to start this one.

Answer (score 1):

The correspondence theorem works with quotients. The quotient you have is $B/A$. The theorem tells you to lift a subgroup of $B/A$ to an intermediate subgroup between $B$ and $A$. You're looking for a subgroup of $B$ of index $k$. You might as well put it between $B$ and $A$, if you're going to use the given information and the tool at hand like you're supposed to. If you do, $B\ge M\ge A$, if we want to know about the index we would use the formula $[B:M]=[B/A:M/A]$. So you're looking for a subgroup of $M/A\le B/A\cong\Bbb Z$ of index $k$. Which is obviously possible.